# GIMP: How to change the color levels of many images according to preset?

Tags: image, colors, gimp

So, I have this dataset of 3k images in grayscale and want to create a colorized respective target to feed them to a model. I decided to do that by changing the RGB color curves. Of course, it is impossible to do this manually for so many images. I couldn't understand how to do this with the python-fu or script-fu. Any ideas?

I know that one way would be to apply the transformation for each channel using OpenCV, the problem with that is that I don't know the equation to the curves that I drew.

Comment: Maybe share the curves you drew, a sample image and the expected result.

Comment: Convert your curves into a list of points and use that as a look up table.

Comment: @fmw42 that makes excellent sense. I managed to do it just using by using a GIMP plugin, but I will use your method to determine the actual transformation.

Comment: See cv2.LUT() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f